# insert a blank line before and after a match on mac OS

Tags: text-processing, sed, files, text-formatting

my file contains the Strings:

```
∗Cast and characters
* Bob Denver is Gilligan
```

I want to insert the line `* ATTENTION *` to any line starting with `*` followed by one OR more spaces. it will be preceded by a blank line and followed by a
blank line inserted above it.
I have:

```
/^\*[ \t]/i\
\* ATTENTION \*
```

it gives me

```
∗Cast and characters
* ATTENTION *
* Bob Denver is Gilligan
```

but I want :

```
∗Cast and characters 

∗ ATTENTION ∗

∗ Bob Denver is Gilligan
```

Note: I have BSD version of sed so i can't use `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were almost there. Just need to add escaped newlines in the inserted text.

```
/^\*[ \t]/i\
\
\* ATTENTION \*\
```

However,  the idiomatic way of doing it, which is posixly, portable, nd avoids backslashing is:

```
/^[*][[:blank:]]/!b
H;s/.*//;x
s/./&** ACHTUNG **&&/
```

Comment: It is nice to see other ways to do it, but I would call the second option obscure at best. Even people used to Sed will stop to think there, while the first one is relatively clear. And the first one is also POSIX.